# Compiling javascript templates with Jammit gem for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, templates, jammit

We're on Rails (3.0.3 / 1.9) using Jammit for static compression and all the other front-end goodies it provides.
I'm trying to work Javscript templates in to replace some ugly front-end code, but it looks like the default JST compiler can't handle Windows line breaks:

assets.yml file:

```
embed_assets: on

javascripts:
  plugins:
  - app/views/**/*.jst
```

When I have _topicPreview.jst all on one line it compiles fine:

```
<div class='TopicPreview <%= typeName %>'><div class='Title'>   <%= summary %> </div><div class='Meta'>  <span class='LastUpdate'>    <%= updatedAt %>  </span>  <span class='PostCount'>    |     <%= postsCount %>     Posts     |  </span>   <span class='LikeCount'>    <%= likesCount %>     Likes  </span>  </div></div>
```

The page loads and I have the JST._topicPreview([JSON version of topic]) method available.  Beautiful.

Half the appeal of JST is the readability / maintainability though, so I would like my JST to have proper formatting.  As soon as I add line breaks into the JST file the page throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL` in `window.JST['_topicPreview'] = template('...[the escaped JST file]...')`

In the code trace I can see that it parses and escapes single quotes, so I was surprised it couldn't handle the line breaks.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?
Is there a cleaner fix than hacking some extra string replaces into the template generation code?

Meta:
I'm pretty new to javascript templates, but should they have their own StackOverflow tag?

**Edit**

Looks like this is a known issue with a pending fix to be merged into the gem.

[Windows line breaks in Jammit JST compiler](https://github.com/documentcloud/jammit/pull/129)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fix has been added to the gem](https://github.com/documentcloud/jammit/pull/129).  Windows developers rejoice.